# Search list of tuples f#

Tags: list, recursion, f#, tuples

Say that I have a self made dictionary made from a list of tuples
`let menu = [("pizza",17);("hotdog",5);("burger", 12);("drink",3);("milkshake",4)]`
I want to write a search function that takes both my dictionary and a key value as a parameter, then returns an option type with the value if key can be found in dict, and `None` if it can't.

I feel like this is a problem built around  [f# recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969362/recursion-in-f-whats-happening), [using and returning option types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Option_Types) as well as [obtaining individual values from a tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples), but I'm having a hell of a time putting them together and getting anything that comes even remotely close to accomplishing this task.

I've come up with some pseudo-code that I believe would solve the problem, but actual f# implementation is another story. In an imperative language this seems like a trivial problem, but trying to grasp functional has been really difficult.

```
//create function `search` accepts dictionary and search key
//match searchkey with dictionary key 
//if searchkey = dictionary key, return option type w/ value
//if searchkey <> dictionary key, recurse call next dict values
//if end of dictionary, doesn't exist, return none 

//Here's a *very* rough sketch of what I think should be happening.

let rec search dict key =
match dict with 
//first check for an empty list, if empty return None
| [] -> None
//next check that there is a head and a tail for dict
//also check for match between first element of head and key
//if match, return hd
//still needs to return option type though, but how?
| hd :: tl when fst hd = key -> snd hd
//finally call search on the tail
| _ :: tl -> search tl key
```

The empty list condition and the wildcard pattern I'm fairly sure are correct, but it's the actual check and return that im stuck on. How might I go about that particular step?

Comment: I think you want `match dict with`. Also, be careful with what you call a dictionary. This is a well known collection in .NET and `dict` is already an F# function that makes a dictionary. Dictionaries provide constant time lookup by key, which your function won't do because it looks through each element one by one.

Comment: I actually just made that change in my own code, I was looking it over and realized that I wanted to match with dict. I'm actually about to update my code. I will be sure to rename dict. Once the code is update, the current issue will be returning the option type! I've been working on it for a while, figure I'll just update my code snip as I make progress. I might even solve it, we'll see. Been at it a long time though -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patterns can be nested inside other patterns. The tuple pattern `(a, b)` can be nested inside the list head/tail pattern `head :: tail` like this: `(a, b) :: tail`

This means the second pattern match can look like this `(k, v) :: _ when k = key`.

You need to return an option from every branch, so either a `Some x` or a `None`. The second match branch was missing a `Some` wrapper.

The code with both changes:

```
let rec search dict key =
    match dict with       
    | [] -> None
    | (k, v) :: _ when k = key -> Some v
    | _ :: tl -> search tl key
```

Comment: Man, I really like f#. It's confusing as hell to learn, but it's so elegant looking. I just updated my original post to what I currently had, and I was getting close! Definitely wouldn't have looked this nice though

Answer (score 1):

They way to think about recursion, is to just get one example right. And leave the remaining list to the recursive function. And you must somehow accomplish that the "remaining" list gets smaller.

First, you deal with a list. One way to think about it is to just check one element at a time. So you extract the first element of a list, do something with it, then repeat the recursive function on the remaining list. So you could start with:

```
let search key lst =
    match lst with
    | head :: tail ->
```

Think of your example list, in this case. The first invocation of your example list your `head` would be `("pizza",17)`.

The next step you now need to-do is. Deconstruct the tuple into `key` and `value` and check them. You deconstruct it with

```
let (k, v) = head
```

Then you need to check if your `k` is equal to `key`. If it is equal, then you want to return the value.

```
if k = key 
then Some v
```

The `else` branch must handle the case where your `k` is not the `key` you search. This is the recursive step. You want to repeat the checking on the remaining list items.

```
else search key tail
```

Remember at this point `tail` is now your `menu` with the first element removed. Currently you have the following code.

```
let rec search key lst =
    match lst with
    | head :: tail ->
        let (k, v) = head
        if   k = key
        then Some v
        else search key tail
```

But this code does not handle the case when it cannot find your item. Think what would happen if the `if k = key` is never true! It will remove one-element at a time, then recursive on the remaining list until you end up with the empty list.

Empty list then means, you didn't find the key. To be successful you now need to add a case for the empty list. In that case your key is not in your list, and you must return "None". So you end up with:

```
let rec search key lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> None
    | head :: tail ->
        let (k, v) = head
        if   k = key
        then Some v
        else search key tail
```

Comment: Would this example be considered purely functional though? I've shied away from if then else statements because I was under the impression that they were not. I do like the let (k, v) = head though, very useful

Comment: Yes. `if` is not an statement in F#. It is an expression that returns a value. That's also why the `else` branch is not optional. You also could write for example.  `let x = if x%2=0 then "Foo" else "Bar"`, because it is an expression. A lot like `... ? ... : ...` in C-like languages.

Comment: @Podo Yeah even local `let` bindings and `match`...`with` are expressions rather than statements in F#. It's worth looking into the difference between statement-oriented vs expression-oriented languages to get a full appreciation for the difference. It's one of my favourite things about F# compared to languages I used before.